# Spring Session and Spring Security (3.2.X RELEASE)

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-java-config, spring-session, xml-configuration

We have a web application built upon Spring Framework 3.2.x (3.2.12-RELEASE at moment) and Spring Security 3.2.x (i.e 3.2.5-RELEASE)

Security is implemented with *classical* Spring approach. In web.xml we load *ApplicationContext* and *springSecurityFilterChain*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
<context-param>
     <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
     <param-value>
        classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
...
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

As of a change in requirements, ***we are trying to investigate on how to permit different HttpSessions per tab (or window) within the same browser***: in this scenario the same physical user can log in the application using two separate app-users.

I can understand that this is not possibile using JSESSIONID cookie approach. I'm trying using Spring Session ([Spring Session and Spring Security](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html5/guides/security.html#security-spring-configuration)
 and [Spring Session Multiple Session](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html5/guides/users.html)) but i can't manage doing it, having difficulties mixing my XML configuration with the JavaConfig approach shown in links before, Tomcat does not even start with a lot of errors.

I'm new with mixing XML and JavaConfig approch, so..can anyone give me an hint in how to proceed with Spring Session?

Are there other ways to fulfill my requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Session project actually contains a few [sample projects](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/tree/master/samples) that demonstrate usage with Spring XML config. Look for the samples with `-xml` suffix in the sample name.

Generally speaking, what you need to do is manually register appropriate `@Configuration` class as a `@Bean`. For example, if you want to use Spring Session backed by Redis, register `RedisHttpSessionConfiguration`. You'll find the correct `@Configuration` class to use by looking at appropriate `@Enable*HttpSession` annotation (in this case `@EnableRedisHttpSession`) and determining which class is imported via `@Import` annotation.